# Is it possible to do one hot encoding with multiple overlapping columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Person   Length   Sport  
  A       1.80     1
  B       1.85     2
  A       1.80     2
```

I tried the following code:

```
pd.get_dummies(data=df, columns=['Sport'])
```

Which gave me the following output:

```
Person Length 1   2
 A      1.80  1   0
 B      1.85  0   1
 A      1.80  0   1
```

I'm trying to get the following output:

```
Person Length 1   2
 A      1.80  1   1
 B      1.85  0   1
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Where is the injury column?

Comment: Use `df = pd.get_dummies(data=df, columns=['Sport']).groupby(df.columns.tolist(), as_index=False).max()`, aggregate `max` by all columns

Comment: @yatu - seems wrong closed question

Comment: My bad @jez reopened

Answer (score 0):

For indicator columns (maximal 1 values) add aggregate `max` by all original columns with [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) of `Sport` column:

```
df = (pd.get_dummies(data=df, columns=['Sport'])
        .groupby(df.columns.difference(['Sport']).tolist(), as_index=False)
        .max())
print (df)
   Length Person  Sport_1  Sport_2
0    1.80      A        1        1
1    1.85      B        0        1
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not the solution. I'm trying to get just two rows, one for person A and one for B. This instead still gives me three rows

Comment: yes, the thing I try to solve is that I want one row for each unique person and his/her length